# error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylibrary

Tags: linux, eclipse, netbeans, shared-libraries

hi I have this error in both eclipse and netbeans, I have mydynamiclib.so file when i add it to eclipse or netbeans and try to build i get the this error netbeans:

> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/myapp] Error 1
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmydynamiclib

I'm using most recent versions of (ubuntu 10.10 ,netbeans, eclipse)

Comment: Is it "mylibrary" or "mydynamiclib"?

Comment: sorry edited it , it's mydynamiclib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <strike>need the libmydynamiclib.a file</strike> as well as the .so file and you should tell ld or gcc where to find it too.

e.g. `gcc -o myapp -L/path/to/lib -lmydynamiclib`

where libmydynamiclib.so lives in /path/to/lib.

<strike>Otherwise, don't link the library, but use dlopen() to load it dynamically.  See the dlopen() manpage.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

The linker can't find your shared library in it's search path.  If you add the directory where your shared lib is to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable the linker should find it and be able to link against it.